# Flex (4) Repeater control overflows contrainer

Tags: actionscript, flex4, air

I have a repeater control in an AIR application, that gets data dynamically. The repeater is inside a panel:

```
        <s:Panel top="50" bottom="10" left="10" right="10">
   <mx:VBox>
    <mx:Repeater id="FeedItemsRptr" dataProvider="{Story_Collection}" height="300">
     <s:Label text="{FeedItemsRptr.currentItem.storyTitle}" />
     <s:RichText text="{FeedItemsRptr.currentItem.storyDesc}" />
     <mx:HRule width="100%"/>
    </mx:Repeater>
   </mx:VBox>
  </s:Panel>
```

However, when the data is bound to the control, the repeater text flows out of the panel container instead of getting scrollbars.

I have tried to encapsulate the repeater inside an  to the same effect, while  is even more unpredictable.

Any idea on how to tame the repeater?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/WFspk.png

---

you can find more on what I wanted to do by going to : http://aphatak.blogspot.com/2010/11/and-take-that-too-times-of-india.html

I have kept some screenshots, flash builder source and compiled bin there; thanks for your help!

Comment: The http://i.imgur.com/WFspk.png has an image to show what I'm talking about. Notice the repeated content going out of borders of the panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution that seems to be working is wrapping up the VBox in a spark:Scroller component like below:

```
<s:Panel width="100%" height="100%" top="50" bottom="10"
         left="10" right="10" title="{FeedItemsRptrCont.height}">
    <s:Scroller width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
            <mx:VBox id="FeedItemsRptrCont" width="100%" height="100%">
                <mx:Repeater id="FeedItemsRptr" width="100%" height="100%" dataProvider="{Story_Collection}">
                    <s:Label text="{FeedItemsRptr.currentItem.storyTitle}" />
                    <s:RichText text="{FeedItemsRptr.currentItem.storyDesc}" />
                    <mx:HRule width="100%" />
                </mx:Repeater>
            </mx:VBox>
        </s:Group>
    </s:Scroller>
</s:Panel>
```

However, what you want to be doing seem to be something that a spark:List would do better than a repeater.